# Query an Entity Framework entity without knowing the object type (class/table) in advance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm wondering, if it's even possible in the first place, how I would go about querying the database (using EF) using an ID and a table name.

For example, writing a function as:

```
QueryDynamicData(string tableName, long entityID){return GetItem(tableName, entityID);}
```

And could be called like:

```
var entry = QueryDynamicData("Person", 143);
```

To clarify, this is for a MVC ASP.Net project using Entity Frameworks.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Following the example from @JPVenson, I came up with the following code. Note that it returns a list of Dictionaries, even though Id is unique, since I'm thinking ahead to when we may want to get all results for a dynamic table instead of just by Id. (This is only proof of concept level)

```
public List<Dictionary<string, object>> QueryDynamicData(string table, int entityID)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the table desired based on the table name passed
            PropertyInfo dbSetInfo = DBContext.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower().Equals(table.ToLower()));

            //Return all results from the table into IQueryable set where Id = entityID passed
            IQueryable anyDbSet = ((IQueryable)dbSetInfo.GetValue(DBContext)).Where("Id=" + entityID);

            List<Dictionary<string,object>> listObjects = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();

            //Iterate through results
            foreach (Object entity in anyDbSet)
            {
                //Create dictionary of Field Name, Field Value from results
                Dictionary<string, object> listDBValues = entity.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(entity));

                //Add dictionary to list of dictionaries - useful for returning list of found results instead of just one
                listObjects.Add(listDBValues);
            }

            //Return list of dictionaries
            return listObjects;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do all your tables have a "id" that can be expressed as a  `long`, and does the "id" column always have the same name?

Comment: Yes, all our tables will have at least a column named "Id" of type long.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. There is a blog from ScottGu

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

(MS Version of DynamicLinq https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki)

that contains the wiki for a lib called DynamicLinq. I'm using it currently in a Project and it will fit your approach.

You still have to wrap it and use some Reflection to build a proper IQueryable but it does a lot of work for you

**Edit Code Example**

With some reflection you can access your dbSet like this (**Untested Pseudocode!**):

```
public object[] QueryDynamicData(string table, int entityId) {    
   //Your DbContext that contains all of your 
   var dbContext = new FooBaa() 
   //Get the DbSet in your DbContext that matches the "Table" name.
   //You are searching for the generic parameter of the DbSet
   var dbSetInfo = dbContext.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(e => e.GetGenericArguments().Any(f => f.Name.Equals(table)); 
   //Now get the DbSet from the DbContext and cast it to an IQueryabe
   IQueryable anyDbSet = (IQueryable)dbSetInfo.GetValue(dbContext);
   //Use Dynamic Linq to create a Query that selects an ID
   //warning SQL-Injection possible checkout the 2nd argument of type IDictionary
   return anyDbSet.Where("Id=" + entityId).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard timing finding the Wiki link you mention, can you post it directly?

Comment: All the examples I can find for this library start with accessing a known `DbSet<>` property on the context.  How would you use the library when the `DbSet<>` property (and therefore, the entity `Type`) are provided by a `string` or not known in advance?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Added an Example

Comment: Tastes best with a generic argument that eliminates the need for an string lookup ;-)

Comment: Nice.  I like this better than my method (I'm not a fan of `dynamic`).

Comment: @BradleyUffner Same here^^ its great but brings a lot of security concerns as this way is danger as hell. We are using the whole range of Dynamic linq and we must do a lot of security checks bevor we fire even one query

Comment: Hm.. I'm wondering if it would be possible to make use of string-interpolation (the way EntityFramework Core does), decomposing an interpolated string to a `FormattableString` instance, to generate a more natural looking query that uses parameters, so it is immune to injection.  I'm going to have to play with this tonight.

Comment: Oh hell yes that would be cool.
https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions
Have a look at the documentation on github.

Comment: Got it working!  Significantly easier than I was expecting. https://pastebin.com/xM2dMbMN . The `PWhere` extension method just decomposes the formatted string and passes on to the Dynamic LINQ call that takes parameters.  Just had to convert the argument format strings from the `{0}` format to `@0`

Comment: Actually, the extension method can just be named `Where`.  Overload resolution picks the correct overload based on the interpolated string matching `FormattableString` more specifically than `string`.  As long as Dynamic LINQ handles parameters correctly, this should too.  I'm really liking this little add-on. `db.Animals.Where($"Name={name}");` is all that's needed to get a dynamic, parameterized Entity Framework query now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a few minutes to work on this between meetings, and came up with this (add it to your `DbContext` class:

```
public dynamic FindEntity(string table, long Id)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(table, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    dynamic dbSet =  prop.GetValue(this, null);
    return dbSet.Find(Id);
}
```

It uses some reflection to find the property on the `DbContext` with the name of the table, and grabs a reference to it.  Then it calls `Find` on that `DbSet<T>` to find the object with the specified primary key.  Since you aren't sending any actual `Type` information along, everything has to be dynamically typed.

You can call it like this:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var e = db.FindEntity("Animals", 1);
}
```

I can't vouch for how useful it will be do you, but it *does* return (dynamically typed) data in my test setup.

Comment: Thanks, that looks really useful! I'll let you know if it works once I try it out.